# Exit file manager when any key press in ubuntu (segmentation fault)

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, themes, filemanager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Now, my file manager is closed on any key pressed so that I can't even do any operation with shortcut like ctrl+c, ctrl+v, etc. But, There is no problem when I open nautilus with root access. I noticed that this is happen right after switching theme from Ambiance to Adwaita. I try to switch back to Ambiance. But that doesn't work. Is there any suggestion how to fix it ?

**Edit**
Just found out the root cause that it's segmentation fault (core dumped). But still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

i've same problem like yours but with 16.04.2 and I removed the ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata folder and it started to work again.